# Table content going outside div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with no set hieght and a min-height of 250px.
When I put in content that is taller than 250px, the div gets longer, as expected.
When I put in a table, the div remains 250px and the table extends outside the div area (in height only, not width).
I tried adding `style="display: block;"` to the table, but that didnt help.
I have no idea why a table specificly would be a problem in this situaltion.
Maybe its a specific CSS thing?

Comment: try using display:inline-block... also if you are using IE7, you might need to add zoom:-1 so that browser understand the positioning...

Comment: Yep. display: inline-block did the trick. Care to post that as an answer so I can give you credit? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using IE7

try using the property. of your div that is miss-behaving.

> display: inline-block

You can create a class that is quick and easy to apply for this problem.

> .inlineblk { 
>     display: inline-block
>   }